# Can i use datatypes.NOW after 6 hours in defaultValue of sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Define a model and set a model's defaultValue to DataTypes.NOW.

But, I want use to Now date after 6 hours.

How can i use it?

```
    LockedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,    
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW, (+ 6hours)
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
LockedAt: {
   type: DataTypes.DATE,    
   allowNull: false,
   defaultValue: sequelize.literal('DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)')
},
```

[Literal](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-literal) is a function that lets you write plain SQL.

Comment: I can't use it. because have error. (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ INTERVAL HOUR,)